# Strange network behavior in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have created an ubuntu VM on virtualbox, the host is windows. For work purposes, I need to use cisco vpn (on the host) to connect to internal servers and access resources. For some strange reason, when connected through the vpn, only internal servers and websites are accessible through ubuntu. But this does not happen on windows, I can still access external sites (eg. google) when connected to the vpn. For certain reasons I cannot use the linux version of cisco vpn. If i disconnect the vpn, all websites are accessible on ubuntu.

The DNS for all these sites is getting resolved, eg. ping google.com and it fetches the ip, but not a single packet is delivered, and 100% is lost. The VM is currently running with the default NAT adapter. If i use any other method (host adapter, bridging etc) and the vpn is not accessible inside the vm.

How do I get external sites also working?

Comment: Do you need Ubuntu to use the vpn? How is the network configuration of Ubuntu, is it NAT?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes I need ubuntu to do work, and its configured with NAT.

Comment: I guess it's trying to connect to the internet using the VPN connection.

Comment: Maybe add a bridged connection to your LAN, and one to your VPN (if possible).

Comment: @davidbaumann I tried that but all internet data seems to be going through only the first connection added. Maybe I can use iptables to route all vpn traffic domains to the vpn interface and the normal traffic to the bridged interface?